# Deadlock between delete and update statement in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-deadlocks

I'm facing a problem in a database between 2 stored procedures, one trying to update and the other wants to delete some huge amount of data.

My `Offer` table contains 50 million rows (I know not a good practice, I'm purging the data).

The table contains an incremental ID (not offer_id) which is the primary key with a clustered index on it.

xml_deadlock_report :

```
  <event name="xml_deadlock_report" package="sqlserver" timestamp="2018-01-02T00:56:16.360Z">
    <data name="xml_report">
        <type name="xml" package="package0" />
        <value>
            <deadlock>
                <victim-list>
                    <victimProcess id="process3697498" />
                </victim-list>
                <process-list>
                    <process id="process3697498" taskpriority="0" logused="127362200" waitresource="PAGE: 9:1:99977592 " waittime="6212" ownerId="32514985656" transactionname="DELETE" lasttranstarted="2018-01-02T01:55:56.853" XDES="0x902e53ed28" lockMode="IX" schedulerid="5" kpid="10104" status="suspended" spid="155" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2018-01-02T00:00:02.427" lastbatchcompleted="2018-01-02T00:00:02.427" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.427" clientapp="SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job 0xAF5CC7B9127279438B52607063734954 : Step 1)" hostname="HB01-BOSQL-CL02" hostpid="5008" loginname="RUEDUCOMMERCE\hicham.boutaleb" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="32514985656" currentdb="9" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088928" clientoption2="128056">
                        <executionStack>
                            <frame procname="EchangesDb.dbo.PurgeGM2" line="433" stmtstart="57518" stmtend="57750" sqlhandle="0x03000900c9c6d33469f20e0158a8000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
DELETE 
                TOP (100000)
                OFFER
            WHERE
                ID IN (SELECT ID FROM #OFFERSTODELETE)
             OPTION(MAXDOP 1)    
                            </frame>
                            <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" sqlhandle="0x010009008b23cd0690ffbc006500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
Exec PurgeGM2    </frame>
                        </executionStack>
                        <inputbuf>
Exec PurgeGM2   </inputbuf>
                    </process>
                    <process id="process5b230c8" taskpriority="0" logused="183626528" waitresource="PAGE: 9:1:99056248 " waittime="2010" ownerId="32514934129" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2018-01-02T01:55:46.243" XDES="0xd0e49f16c0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="15" kpid="10684" status="suspended" spid="128" sbid="0" ecid="22" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2018-01-02T01:55:46.240" lastbatchcompleted="2018-01-02T01:55:46.240" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.240" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="HB01-BIZTALK01" hostpid="2620" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="32514934129" currentdb="9" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673317152" clientoption2="128056">
                        <executionStack>
                            <frame procname="EchangesDb.dbo.offer_insert_diff" line="183" stmtstart="8450" stmtend="8780" sqlhandle="0x0300090048642c329947700146a8000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE o
            SET tc_process_status = 0
            FROM [dbo].[offer] AS o WITH(NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN Temp_OffersToMove AS t WITH(NOLOCK) ON (o.offer_id = t.offer_id)    </frame>
                        </executionStack>
                        <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 9 Object Id = 841770056]   
                        </inputbuf>
                    </process>
                </process-list>
                <resource-list>
                    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="99977592" dbid="9" subresource="FULL" objectname="EchangesDb.dbo.offer" id="lock3d70957380" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057595568062464">
                        <owner-list>
                            <owner id="process5b230c8" mode="U" />
                        </owner-list>
                        <waiter-list>
                            <waiter id="process3697498" mode="IX" requestType="wait" />
                        </waiter-list>
                    </pagelock>
                    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="99056248" dbid="9" subresource="FULL" objectname="EchangesDb.dbo.offer" id="lock6d7712ab80" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057595568062464">
                        <owner-list>
                            <owner id="process3697498" mode="IX" />
                        </owner-list>
                        <waiter-list>
                            <waiter id="process5b230c8" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
                        </waiter-list>
                    </pagelock>
                </resource-list>
            </deadlock>
        </value>
    </data>
</event>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and thanks all for your help.

My problem was solved by [Erland's](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0236bdaa-a1c0-413e-a09e-d91de75c1ddb/deadlock-between-delete-and-update-statment-sql-2012?forum=sqldatabaseengine) suggestions and some extra work :

1) Reduce batch size(find the good threeshold, for me 5000).

2) Set deadlock priorty low for the purge.

3) Add retry for deadlocks in the purge(for 1025 errors).

4)reduce the size of my temp table containing the rows to delete after each iteration(delete top 5000 from order by id)

and now it works fine.

many thnaks.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter that `Offer.Offer_Id` isn't the primary key.  Locks cover rows, pages, or tables, not columns.  If one field in a table changes, the entire row is locked at a minimum.

Based on how it's written, I'm assuming that your deletion procedure is running this statement:

```
DELETE TOP (100000) OFFER
WHERE ID IN (
        SELECT ID
        FROM #OFFERSTODELETE
        )
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

in a loop of some sort, probably with commits (and possibly checkpoints) on each iteration, until no rows are deleted?  And `#OFFERSTODELETE` is probably several million rows?

You may be able to reduce the probability of deadlocks by reducing the number of rows deleted with each iteration.  Say, to `100` or `500`.  This will reduce the number of locks as well as reducing the probability of escalating locks to page or table locks.  It will take longer overall that way, of course, but it will be less lock heavy.  It would also be a good idea to run your deletion overnight if your users all share a timezone, or (even better) during a scheduled downtime.  You could then potentially remove the `MAXDOP` restriction and not worry about CPU usage.

Beyond that, it's not really possible to make any suggestions without seeing the entirety of each procedure.  You may be able to rewrite the two procedures so that they don't deadlock each other.  Unfortunately, that's just not always possible.

Also:

> My `Offer` table contains 50 million rows (I know not a good practice, I'm purging the data).

There's nothing *inherently* wrong with a table this size.  It's not even particularly large, truth be told.  If you have a good clustering index and always filter your data appropriately, you shouldn't have a tremendous performance impact due to table size.  As long as you're performing routine statistics and index maintenance, you may not have any problems at all.